# ios youtube embedded video frame issue

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, uiwebview

I am trying to embed a video from youtube with the following code:

```
func setUpVideo() {
    let width = webView.frame.width
    let height = webView.frame.height
    let frame = 0
    bmiWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    let videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/GCALWdwKr48"
    let htmlUrl = "<html><body><iframe width=\(width) height=\(height) src=\(videoUrl)?&playsinline = 1 frameborder=\(frame) allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"
    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlUrl, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)
}
```

I'm able to load the video initially with white background but when it loads it looks like below. I'm not sure why there is a white background. If someone can tell me how to remove that will be really helpful. Thank you.
[image: youtube]

Comment: The best way for that is ---> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper and for other library for swift is https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player

Answer (score 1):

The white background is the margin on the body of the HTML of your UIWebView.

Add some CSS to set the margin to 0 like so:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>body{margin:0px;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe width=\(width) height=\(height) src=\(videoUrl)?&playsinline = 1 frameborder=\(frame) allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```